# Why can static member function definitions not have the keyword 'static'?

Tags: c++, static

As per [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) link on the 'static' keyword in C++ :

> The static keyword is only used with the declaration of a static
>   member, inside the class definition, but **not with the definition of
>   that static member**.

Why is the static keyword prohibited on member function definitions? I do understand that re-declaring a function as 'static' at its definition is redundant. But using it should be harmless during compilation of the function definition as it does not result in any kind of ambiguity. So why do compilers prohibit it?

Comment: `static` on an out-of-class function definition means *internal linkage*, however class member functions have external linkage. It'd be confusing

Comment: Compiler is always in a state to figure out if a function is a member-function or a global-function. Shouldn't be too confusing for it. :-/

Comment: @M.M but he's talking about class member functions.

Comment: @MichaelWalz no kidding

Comment: @aakashbhowmick it's confusing for humans reading the code, not for the compiler.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's ambiguity alright. The same definition need not be for a member function at all.

Consider this:

```
namespace foo {
    static void bar();
}

static void foo::bar() {

}
```

`foo::bar` is **required** to be defined with the same linkage specifier.

For member functions, however, `static` is not a linkage specifier. If it was allowed, the correctness of the definition of `foo::bar` will be *very very* context dependent on what `foo` is. Disallowing `static` in fact eases the burden on the compiler.

Extending it to members in general, as opposed to just member functions, is a matter of consistency.

Comment: Delphi referred to such functions as "class" functions rather than "static", using the `class` keyword to indicate them.  With hindsight, that may have been a better idea for C++, rather than re-using "static" for a totally different thing...

Comment: @MarkKCowan - "Overloading" a keyword (and one inherited from C, no less) wasn't the best idea, I agree. I'm not sure using `class` would have been better (partially because structs and classes are interchangeable, what then? A "struct" member function?). Perhaps an entirely different keyword would have been better. Then compilers could have been made less context dependent then they are today.

Comment: class is already overloaded for template arguments, where "struct" can't be used in its place even though we can template structs

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it provides a good reason why compilers would want to enforce this rule.

Comment: @MarkKCowan - But it's not a case where the mismatch is glaring. If you define a type with the struct keyword, it would be quite weird to designate the function with "class". Well, IMO anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The point is, that `static` has several, very different meanings:

```
class Foo {
    static void bar();
}
```

Here the `static` keyword means that the function `bar` is associated with the class `Foo`, but it is not called on an instance of `Foo`. This meaning of `static` is strongly connected to object orientation. However, the declaration

```
static void bar();
```

means something very different: It means that `bar` is only visible in file scope, the function cannot be called directly from other compilation units.

You see, if you say `static` in the class declaration, it does not make any sense to later restrict the function to file scope. And if you have a `static` function (with file scope), it does not make sense to publish it as part of a class definition in a public header file. *The two meanings are so different, that they practically exclude each other.*

---

`static` has even more, distinct meanings:

```
void bar() {
    static int hiddenGlobal = 42;
}
```

is another meaning, that is similar, but not identical to

```
class Foo {
    static int classGlobal = 6*7;
}
```

When programming, words don't always the same meaning in all contexts.

Comment: The question was not about the different meanings of 'static' in C++. As a decent C++ programmer, I am aware of all of these.

Comment: @aakashbhowmick But you asked why your compiler won't allow you to combine two of these different meanings, seemingly thinking, the `static` would have the same effect in both cases. When you use `static` on a function outside of class scope, it is entirely different from when you use it within class scope.

Comment: I'm quite clear about how a static member-function is different from a static global-function. My question was why should a static member-function **definition** NOT contain the keyword 'static', though the **declaration** of the same function can ( and should).

Comment: @AAkashbhowmick Well, syntactically, there would be no difference between a static member-function definition and a file scope function definition. The only difference between the two definitions is, that the member function definition generally needs to use the scope resolution operator. However, that operator may also appear on a file scope function if it's part of a namespace, so it's no syntactic difference, only a semantic one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the difference between declaration and implementation, and that will answer your question:

Declaration: Is how C++ functions and methods are seen before compiling the program. It's put in a header file (.h file).

Implementation: Is how the compiler links a declaration to a real task in binary code. The implementation can be compiled on the fly (from source files, .cpp or .cxx or .cc), or can be already compiled (from shared libraries or object files).

Now going back to your question, when you declare something as static, it's something not related to the implementation, but related to how the compiler sees the decleration while compiling the code. For example, if you label functions in source files "static", then that's meaningless, because that information cannot be carried to compiled objects and shared libraries. Why allow it? On the contrary, it could only cause ambiguity.

For the exact same reason, default parameters must go into the header, not the source files. Because source files (that contain implementations), cannot carry the default parameter information to a compiled object.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess but if the definition has static it could be interpreted as a file-scope variable in the C sense.